# Java webapplication deploymant with relational database

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, war

We can deploy a web application in java container using a war. But how schema creation is handled with deployment?

Is there a way to include schema and tables creation statements with war? Or do we have to create schema with required tables manually?

How database setup is normally handled with war deployment in a java container like tomcat?

Comment: Deploying a database has no direct relation to deploying your application. It is possible to have the application deploy the db, but generally it will be a separate process.

Comment: If you are using an ORM framework, it is possible to create the tables through configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Usually during development any action with DB is performed by your ORM(ex. Hibernate). But in production mode it's not applicable and you should use some additional tools.

For example in our project we are using [Flyway](http://flywaydb.org/).